# LinearProgressIndicator animation Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a page with a page slider carousel and a progress bar. When the carousel moves to another page I want that the progress bar updates from a value to another with an animation.
I tried `LinearProgressIndicator` but I don't know how to set animation from the old value to new one. This is what I have

```
LinearProgressIndicator(
  minHeight: 2,
  value: currentPageIndex/(pages.length - 1)
)
```

`currentPageIndex` is updated with `setState()` method externally.

Is there any way to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include full widget that will reproduce the same issue, and it will help you to find better answer

Answer (score 38):

The 'recommended' way is to use `TweenAnimationBuilder`, which you can learn more about [here](https://youtu.be/6KiPEqzJIKQ). Essentially this is a simple animation that does not really need external controllers.

Take this code for example:

```dart
TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
    curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    tween: Tween<double>(
        begin: 0,
        end: <your-current-value>,
    ),
    builder: (context, value, _) =>
        LinearProgressIndicator(value: value),
),
```

You can change the duration of the animation and the curve of the animation. When you update your value, the progress indicator should automatically animate between the previous value and the new value!

Comment: This answer should be accepted as the correct answer.