# Animating LinearProgressIndicator within bloc pattern

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, bloc

I have a bloc which emits states that contain some progress value (0-100%). This value is to be displayed with `LinearProgressIndicator`. Updates may occur in chunks, meaning progress can jump from, say, 0% to 30% in a single step.

Below is a simple snippet to reproduce this behavior:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class StartProgressEvent {}

class ProgressState {
  final double progress;
  ProgressState(this.progress);
}

class ProgressBloc extends Bloc<StartProgressEvent, ProgressState> {
  ProgressBloc() : super(ProgressState(0)) {
    on<StartProgressEvent>(_startProgress);
  }

  void _startProgress(
    StartProgressEvent event,
    Emitter<ProgressState> emit,
  ) async {
    emit(ProgressState(0.1));
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));

    emit(ProgressState(0.4));
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));

    emit(ProgressState(0.7));
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));

    emit(ProgressState(1.0));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(const DemoApp());
}

class DemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const DemoApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: BlocProvider<ProgressBloc>(
            create: (context) => ProgressBloc()..add(StartProgressEvent()),
            child: BlocBuilder<ProgressBloc, ProgressState>(
              builder: (context, state) => LinearProgressIndicator(value: state.progress),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This snippet shows the following indicator:

[image: linear progress indicator]

Instead of updating instantly, I want my indicator to animate ongoing changes, i.e. to update smoothly from its previous state to the current one.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73652605/1815052) suggesting that we use `TweenAnimationBuilder` to animate `LinearProgressIndicator` but it implies that we know its current value which we don't.

In a broader sense this question is not limited to progress indicator. I believe it can be framed this way: how can we animate between two consecutive "states" of a widget (either stateless or stateful) within bloc architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `AnimatedFractionallySizedBox` with your duration instead of LinearProgressIndicator

```dart
class DemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const DemoApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            BlocProvider<ProgressBloc>(
              create: (context) => ProgressBloc()..add(StartProgressEvent()),
              child: BlocBuilder<ProgressBloc, ProgressState>(
                  builder: (context, state) => AnimatedFractionallySizedBox(
                        duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        widthFactor: state.progress,
                        child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: 10,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      )

                  // LinearProgressIndicator(value: state.progress),
                  ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But it feels more like a hack :) I believe it must be a common requirement to animate such changes when new state emits. Isn't there some more or less conventional solution for that?

Comment: It depends, if you like  to fixed on `_startProgress`  you can use any animated widget on UI side, AnimatedBuilder will provide you more control,  but for simple case, AnimatedContainer will also work, I choose `AnimatedFractionallySizedBox`  while I skipped getting width