# Show Progress of Isolate with ProgressIndicator()

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Project I have a heavy async task which is executed in a secondary Isolate.

I want to display the progress of this task to the UI with a `ProgressIndicator()`.

I tried using a callback function passed to the Isolate as a parameter, but this did not work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class IsolateProgress extends StatelessWidget {
  const IsolateProgress({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Isolate Progress')),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: compute(_heavyTask, [1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111, 96953, 111111, 99971, 11111111, 999999487]),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Map<int, bool>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data!.entries.map((e) => Text('${e.key}: ${e.value ? 'prime' : 'no prime'}')).toList(),
            );
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                // value: x (from Isolate),
                ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Map<int, bool>> _heavyTask(List<int> listToCheck) async {
    Map<int, bool> result = {};
    for (int num in listToCheck) {
      // async call on each loop
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
      if (num == 1) {
        result[1] = false;
      }
      result[num] = true;
      for (int i = 2; i < num; ++i) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
          result[num] = false;
        }
      }
      // here: somehow send a message to main Isolate to add a step to CircularProgressIndicator()
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: use [SendPort](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/SendPort-class.html) and call it's `send` method on each progress update, check also [ReceivePort](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/ReceivePort-class.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Isolate version)
You need to create ReceivePort and sendPort to communicate between different Isolate.

```
import 'dart:isolate';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HeavyTaskData {
  HeavyTaskData({required this.progress, this.result});

  double progress;
  Map<int, bool>? result;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{progress:$progress, result:$result}';
  }
}

class IsolateProgress extends StatelessWidget {
  const IsolateProgress({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Isolate Progress')),
      body: StreamBuilder<HeavyTaskData>(
        stream: _heavyTaskStreamReceiver([
          1,
          11,
          111,
          1111,
          11111,
          96953,
          111111,
          99971,
          11111111,
          999999487
        ]),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<HeavyTaskData> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data!.result != null && snapshot.data!.progress == 1) {
              return ListView(
                children: snapshot.data!.result!.entries
                    .map((e) =>
                        Text('${e.key}: ${e.value ? 'prime' : 'no prime'}'))
                    .toList(),
              );
            }
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              value: snapshot.data?.progress ?? 0,
              // value: x (from Isolate),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void heavyTask(List<dynamic> args)async{
    Map<int, bool> result = {};
    SendPort sendPort = args[0];
    List<int> listToCheck = args[1];

    double progress = 0;
    for (int num in listToCheck) {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
      if (num == 1) {
        result[1] = false;
      }
      result[num] = true;
      for (int i = 2; i < num; ++i) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
          result[num] = false;
        }
      }
      progress = result.length/listToCheck.length;
      sendPort.send(HeavyTaskData(progress: progress,result:result));
    }
    sendPort.send(HeavyTaskData(progress: progress,result:result));
  }

  Stream<HeavyTaskData> _heavyTaskStreamReceiver(List<int> listToCheck) async* {
    final receivePort = ReceivePort();
    Isolate.spawn(heavyTask,[receivePort.sendPort,listToCheck]);
    await for (var message in receivePort){
      if(message is HeavyTaskData){
        yield message;
        if(message.progress >= 1){
          receivePort.close();
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That works like a charm, thank you. To improve it even more I added a TweenAnimationBuilder to the CircularProgressIndicator(). See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70127096/linearprogressindicator-animation-flutter) for anyone interested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on how to return Stream from Isolate.
But is this what you need?(Async version)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HeavyTaskData{
  HeavyTaskData({required this.progress,this.result});
  final double progress;
  final Map<int, bool>? result;
}

class IsolateProgress extends StatelessWidget {
  const IsolateProgress({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Isolate Progress')),
      body: StreamBuilder<HeavyTaskData>(
        stream:_heavyTask([1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111, 96953, 111111, 99971, 11111111, 999999487]),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<HeavyTaskData> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if(snapshot.data!.result!=null){
              return ListView(
                children: snapshot.data!.result!.entries.map((e) => Text('${e.key}: ${e.value ? 'prime' : 'no prime'}')).toList(),
              );
            }
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              value: snapshot.data?.progress??0,
              // value: x (from Isolate),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Stream<HeavyTaskData> _heavyTask(List<int> listToCheck) async*{
    Map<int, bool> result = {};
    for (int num in listToCheck) {
      // async call on each loop
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
      if (num == 1) {
        result[1] = false;
      }
      result[num] = true;
      for (int i = 2; i < num; ++i) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
          result[num] = false;
        }
      }
      // here: somehow send a message to main Isolate to add a step to CircularProgressIndicator()
      yield HeavyTaskData(progress: result.length/listToCheck.length);
    }
     yield HeavyTaskData(progress: result.length/listToCheck.length,result:result ) ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but with this approach the heavy task still runs on the main isolate and freezes the UI with high numbers (as you wrote before). The challenge I am facing is moving the heavy task to a second isolate an returning kind of a Stream to the main Isolate.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).